# $L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a metric space and $\Omega$ is open in $L(\mathbb{R}^n)$. How to image $\Omega$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am reading "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin.

> **9.8 Theorem** *Let $\Omega$ be the set of all invertible linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> (a) If $A\in\Omega$, $B\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $$||B-A||\cdot||A^{-1}||<1,$$ then $B\in\Omega.$
>
> (b) $\Omega$ is an open subset of $L(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and the mapping $A\to A^{-1}$ is continuous on $\Omega$.*

$L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a metric space and $\Omega$ is open in $L(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
I cannot image what $\Omega$ is in $L(\mathbb{R}^n).$
For example, we image $\{A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)\mid ||A||<r\}$ as an open ball whose radius is $r$ and whose center is $O$.
How to image $\Omega$ visually?
I am interested in the geometrical properties of $\Omega$.
I know $\Omega$ is open in $L(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
What are other important geometrical properties of $\Omega$?

Comment: You can think of $\Omega$ as the set of all matrices with nonzero determinant (this gives openness immediately). Then a small ball in the space is basically a set of small perturbations of a matrix.

Comment: @William Thank you very much for your answer.